# Reading a string in as a txt file name in c++

Tags: c++, file, filestream

So I have a program that will read in arguments from the command line. One of my arguments is a text file in the folder. I'm trying to open this txt file and read the lines in it, but in order to do so I need to put the specific txt file in double quotes like so: "text.txt". Is there a way to do this if the text file's name is stored in a string?

by the way, opening the file should look something like this:

```
    std::ifstream text ("textfile.txt")
```

Comment: I don't see why you need to wrap it in quotes if it's in a string. The quotes in the code delimit a string litteral. In the command line argument they're used amongst other reasons in case there are spaces in the text argument.

Comment: `argv[1]` should contain the character array you want to pass to the `std::ifstream` constructor.

Comment: You seem to be confusing the command line interpreter's requirement to quote spaces with how the argument is actually passed to your program. And what is your question? *"Is there a way to do this?"* is fairly vague if you don't explain what *this* is.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string filename = argv[index];//Where index is the position of the filename argument
std::ifstream text(filename.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);
```

Comment: Why `#include <cstdlib>` ?

Comment: including cstdlib is just a force of habit. I removed it since it was not relevant to the question